# Django returns if request.method statement false and returns blank template

Tags: django, file, templates, upload

I'm trying to do a simple file upload for my project, but there seems to be a problem. So, once a user is logged, I try to upload a file by clicking a button, but the result is a blank template.

Here is my upload function in views.py:

```
def model_form_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('main:register')
        else:
            return render(request, 'main/model_form_upload.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        return render(request, 'main/user_panel.html')
```

Class in forms.py:

```
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ('description', 'document')
```

Class in models.py:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And the url:

```
url(r'^upload/$', views.model_form_upload, name='upload')
```

In model_form_upload.html I have just this:

```html
{% extends 'main/user_base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
  </form>

  <p><a href="{% url 'main:upload' %}">Return to home</a></p>
{% endblock %}
```

I attempt to render the template by clicking a button and it looks like this:

```html
<a href="{%url 'main:upload'%}" class="btn btn-primary"><font face="Ubuntu">Upload</font></a>
```

The main problem is that, after a bit of checking and searching, I found out that it doesn't return anything mainly because the `if request.method == 'POST'` statement in `model_form_upload` view returns `False`, and so it just renders the template without the form. So I don't really understand why it seems to return false there.

Comment: Have you tried `<input type="submit">` instead of button?

Comment: I tried, doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: Nevermind, I had missed the crux of the question, which @xyres had already spotted.

Answer (score 1):

Your view will only process the form, or return a form in case of a `POST` request.

But you are making a request to your view by clicking on a link, which is making a `GET` request, not a `POST` request.

Since, links can't make a `POST` request, you'll have to either use JS to do that, or you can create a small form like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'main:upload' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

You can style the `submit` button with CSS to look like a normal link. When you'll click on it, a `POST` request will go to your view and it will return the upload form in the response.

---

The above technique of using a small from instead of a link is also used by many websites for the "Logout" functionality to limit the logout action only to a `POST` request.

---

**UPDATE:**

You want to show an empty upload form, right? Well, in that case, why not render an empty form for a `GET` request.

Here's what it will do:

1. If request method is `POST`, process the form data.
2. If form is valid, save the data. Then redirect to `'main:register'`.
3. If form is invalid, render the same template with the form.
4. If request method is `GET`, create empty form instance and render it.

Here's the code:

```
def model_form_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('main:register')
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()

    return render(request, 'main/model_form_upload.html', {'form': form})
```

Now, you can visit the upload page the old way via the regular `<a href="{% url 'main:upload' %}">` link.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that seems to not change anything, I still get a blank template

Comment: @CatalinC Where (in which file) did you put this code?

Comment: I put it in the template called user_panel.html where I originally put the button with the upload, and from there to return another one with the upload form

Comment: @CatalinC Does that mean you now have two buttons in that template? You'd need to click the one inside the form. And the form needs `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, as the one in the other template.

Comment: @CatalinC And you need the actual form field with the file. Where is the document you are trying to upload coming from, in a link?

Comment: @CatalinC I've updated the answer with an alternative approach. Maybe, you'll find that useful.

Comment: Alright, so I only have one button (which I have changed from <button> to <input> ) that I click and then that gets me another template in which to display the upload form. And the problem is that it doesn't happen anything even after I put enctype="multipart/form-data". The problem is, in the other template, model_form_upload.html, it won't show any kind of buttons or whatever I put there just for testing, not necessarily the upload form. I wanted to see if at least I could print a simple text that is just part of the template itself, but it won't show it.

Comment: @CatalinC See xyres's update to the question. I thought you wanted to click the button to upload a file (and the original answer got you halfway there), but you just want to go to the upload form. Then the problem is how you are handling the `else:` in the upload view. The first request to that kind of view is always a `GET` (for the empty form), only the second request (after clicking submit) is a `POST`.

Comment: I'm sorry if I appear to be really clumsy, that function should do the job, but it just keeps the template blank. I also use the old <a href> in user_panel.html, and from there I use a form with <input> from model_form_upload.html, as suggested in the very first answer for the actual file upload, which should show up technically. The function is alright, but it just won't show anything. Once again, I'm sorry if quite the headache, but I just don't get it why it doesn't work.

Comment: @CatalinC Can you create a new minimal, barebones project that reproduces this problem and email that to me so I can take a loot at it first hand? If you don't mind, of course.  My email info is in my profile.

Comment: I'll try that and I'll send it

Comment: I just sent the email

Comment: Alright, so apparently, the problem was like this: instead of {% block content %} in model_form_upload.html if I put {% block body  %} it works just fine. It really amazes me how much of a simple modification this was and yet...Anyway, thank you so much for all your help and sorry for all this hassle :)

Comment: @CatalinC That's great. All the best with your project.